# Wordpress category page title not showing

Tags: wordpress

I working for a news website using wordpress. Now I face a problem that is when I visit any category page using cat id category title not showing. But when I visit using name permalink it show correctly. How I solve this problem?

In this link category link showing correctly:

http://localhost/wordpress/category/short-news/

But in this link not showing:

http://localhost/wordpress/?cat=7

Using code for category title is:

```
<?php single_term_title(); ?> or <?php single_cat_title("", true); ?>
```

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: So, where is the code?

Comment: Why you not decide for one of the ways? Visit by Cat ID or permalink? See WordPress settings Permalink